# Can't find element using selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I have the following function in my script that looks for an element and when it finds it, it looks for another element. However, it only finds the first element, it never finds the second element.

The second element appears as a message, does not exist for a period of time and then appears, while the first element always exists but is only visible for a moment. The xpath is correct because when it appears and I look for it with inspection element cntrl + f if it appears.

This is the function:

`def check_objects(browser, wait, object1_xpath, object2_xpath):
object1 = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, object1_xpath)))
print("First object found:")

```
try:
    object2 = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, object2_xpath)), timeout=2)
    print("Second object found:")


    return True
except:
    print("Second object not found.")
    return False`
```

**UPDATE**, if I change the order in which it looks for the objects and then looks for object2 first then it does find it. Something must be wrong with the function. The problem is not that I'm using EC.presence_of_element_located() . Because element2 is not that it is not visible, but that it is simply not there for a period of time and then it appears so both could be used.